# Does ibm websphere esb support https?

Tags: https, websphere, esb

I tried looking for any article mentioning HTTPS but I only get the generic HTTP binding material, no mention of HTTP Secure.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found much specific tutorial material. The general approach is alluded to [here in the InfoCenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v7r0mx/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wesb.doc/doc/tsec_sslwebservice.html) The fundamental point being that the ESB is giving access to Web Services and the HTTPS or SSL connectivity is defined largely in the Web Service itself.

It seems like is you search for SSL you get more extensive results, for example [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21255616)

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried reading through the links, and from what I understood is that I build my web service as usual then configure for SSL when I deploy it on the WebSphere Application Server - is this correct? I had previous experience with Mule ESB and the http/s configuration is done inside of the application, not on the application server.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a web server (with SSL) in front of WAS.